# How to retrieve a list in Firebase database folder?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have a folder in my Database called "Cars", within the folder is a list of car brands, I want to retrieve all the brands and put it in a UITableView. Then when you press on a brand it will show the models of the brand. I have a trouble retrieving the list of cars at the moment. This is the screenshot of my Database and my code for the view controller.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import SDWebImage

struct carStruct {
    let cars : String!

}

class CarMakeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    var cars = [carStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Cars")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.childrenCount)
            for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                guard let value = rest.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> else { continue }
                guard let  make = value["Cars"] as? String else { continue }
                let cars = carStruct(cars: make)
                self.cars.append(cars)
            }

        self.cars = self.cars.reversed(); self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cars.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellMake")

        let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(21) as! UILabel
        label1.text = cars[indexPath.row].cars

        return cell!
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say you have trouble getting the list of cars at the moment, what happens when you try to get them?

Comment: nothing appears @JenPerson

Comment: Is it an issue where the UI is being updated on a background thread?  Try something like `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData( ) }`. *disclaimer: haven't fully studied the code, just the first thing to jump out at me.

Comment: I don't think thats the problem, I double checked. Im using the same code to retrieve Users and it works fine but not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't work @TaylorM

Comment: For the sake of clarity: what happens when you print the snapshot. Because Taylor is right, you should update the table asynchronously.

Comment: it prints out the number of items in this case 2

Comment: @Riccardo Check once tableVIew `delegate` and `datasource` is connected or not.

Comment: it is connected @NiravD

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make another struct for holding data that is inside of the model of the car (so, for this struct you should dig little bit deeper). As for retrieving data now, I suggest you to read [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2) article, which helped me a lot not long ago.